# Adding new object to mapped property - KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am attempting to load a ViewModel property with mapped data on initial page load and then at a later time, append new JSON data to this mapped property. Following the docs here (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html), it would appear that all I need to do is call `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, someObject);` to combine `data` and `someObject`. Can someone tell me why this would not work? Please see fiddle example below:

http://jsfiddle.net/m4uKe/

I would expect

```
{
  "Foo": [
    {
      "Property": "Value1"
    }
  ]
}
```

to become

```
{
  "Foo": [
    {
      "Property": "Value1"
    },
    {
      "Property": "Value2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `push` an item to the observable array obtained from the first call to `fromJS`. So change this line:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data2, {}, self.Foo);
```

to this

```
self.Foo.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(data2));
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/m4uKe/2/

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. One follow-up I'd like to add: if you just push `data2` like this, it will not be observable like the rest of the elements originally mapped. So the fix I did for this was to map `data2` itself and then push it. `self.Foo.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(data2));`

Comment: Ah, yes. I missed that. Good shout. I'll update the answer too for future visitors.